# Anonymous usort function rewrite to PHP 5.2

Tags: php, anonymous-function, usort

I need help with rewriting this part of code (PHP > 5.3):

```
usort($arr,function($a,$b)use($var){return $a[$var]>$b[$var]?-1:$a[$var]!=$b[$var];});
```

to PHP 5.2:

```
usort($arr,create_function('$a, $b','global $var; return $a[$var]>$b[$var]?-1:$a[$var]!=$b[$var];'));
```

Now I've got an error:

```
PHP Notice: Undefined index: in file.php(23) : runtime-created function on line 1,
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Either `$a` or `$b` doesn't have an index `$var`. Do `print_r($a);` for both arrays all see how the structure looks like

Comment: Is `$var` **really** global, or is it local in the main function scope?

Comment: wrap it in an if-statement `if ( ! empty($a[ $var ]) &&  ! empty($b[ $var ]) )`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the `$var` you were using is not a global variable, but a local variable in whatever scope this code was in. (If it were really a global variable, then you wouldn't have to use `use ($var)`; you could just use `global $var;` inside the function instead.) In that case, when you try to access a "global" `$var` inside the function, it would access an undefined variable which would give an empty value, and when you try to use this empty value to index your array, it fails to lookup because that value is not a key.

If `$var` really is a local variable, you can use it with something like this:

```
usort($arr,
    create_function('$a, $b', '$var = '.var_export($var,true).';
        return $a[$var]>$b[$var]?-1:$a[$var]!=$b[$var];
    ')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll pretty much have to use a class to capture the variable then:

```
class Comp {

    protected $key;

    public function __construct($key) {
        $this->key = $key;
    }

    public function compare(array $a, array $b) {
        return $b[$this->key] - $a[$this->key];
    }

}

usort($arr, array(new Comp($var), 'compare'));
```